# prove that any continuous bijection from $S^2$ to itself is is an homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Let $S^2=\{(x,y,z)\space:\space x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \}$ be a subspace of $(\mathbb R^3,d_{euclid})$.
 prove that every continuous bijection $F\space:\space S^2\rightarrow S^2$ is an homeomorphism from $S^2$ to itself.
I couldn't find any property of $S^2$ that in addition to the demands on $F$ will imply that $F^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: I haven't had my caffeine this morning, but isn't every bijection invertible?

Comment: yes but it still doesn't imply that the invert function is continuous...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is always a homeomorphism, which one can show by showing that the preimage of any closed set is closed.

Comment: yes I just figured it out thank you, yet if there is any metric proof I would like to see it.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the result that every continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff one is a homeomorphism you can use that (provided you can show the assumptions here!).